# VueJs Dialog Reusable Component with buttons different action

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dialog, vuetify.js

I am trying to build a reusable component that called `v-dialog`.
The idea is that I when the the dialog pop up there will be consist of 2 buttons which is called `submit` and `cancel`.

For the `submit` button of dialog component will be linked with different actions based on user clicks which button.

For example `button A` will call function name `A` and `button B` will call function name `B` and so on when user clicks on `submit` button of the dialog.

Let's say this is a component file I called `DialogReusable.vue`

```
<v-dialog
v-model="dialog"
                  persistent
                  max-width="300"
                >
                  <v-card>
                    <v-card-title
                      class="text-h5"
                      style="word-break: break-word"
                    >
                      Title
                    </v-card-title>
                    <v-card-actions>
                      <v-spacer />
                      <v-btn
                        color="green darken-1"
                        text
                        @click="dialog = false"
                      >
                        Cancel Button
                      </v-btn>
                      <v-btn
                        class="primary"
                        @click="functionSubmits()"
                      >
                        Submit
                      </v-btn>
                    </v-card-actions>
                  </v-card>
                </v-dialog>
```

And this is the parent file that I called `MainParent.vue`
For this file it has like 3 buttons which link to different function.

When user clicks on each button the `Dialog` should appears and when user clicks on the `submit` button of the dialog then it will call the respective function name that I set `@click` on each button.

```
                <v-btn
                  v-if="condition"
                  color="primary"
                  dark
                  @click="functionA()"
                >
                  Function A
                </v-btn>
                <v-btn
                  v-if="condition"
                  class="primary"
                  @click="functionB()"
                >
                  Function B
                </v-btn>
                <v-btn
                  v-if="condition"
                  class="primary"
                  @click="functionC()"
                >
                  Function C
                </v-btn>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the concept of passing the functions through `props` attribute in Vue.

Let's me show you the first example of passing the function from parent into child component.

**Getting a value from the parent**

If you want a child component to access a parent's method, it seems obvious to just pass the method straight down as a prop.

```
<!-- Parent -->
<template>
  <ChildComponent :method="parentMethod" />
</template>

// Parent
export default {
  methods: {
    parentMethod() {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

And you child component would be like:

```
// Child
export default {
  props: {
    method: { type: Function },
  },
  mounted() {
    // Use the parent function directly here
    this.method();
  }
}
```

**Getting a value from the child**

Other case you might want to get a value from child into parent component, for example the function in parent component has a param name.

```
<!-- Parent -->
<template>
  <ChildComponent :method="parentMethod" />
</template>

// Parent
export default {
  methods: {
    parentMethod(valueFromChild) {
      // Do something with the value
      console.log('From the child:', valueFromChild);
    }
  }
}
```

Where in the child component you pass the value in when calling it:

```
// Child
export default {
  props: {
    method: { type: Function },
  },
  mounted() {
    // Pass a value to the parent through the function
    this.method("some param name");
  }
}
```

Regarding you question, I think you can achieve by the following:

Let's say you have 3 submit buttons and each button has different action.

First let's create the reusable pop up dialog that acts like a child component.

```
<template>
  <v-dialog
    :value="dialog"
    persistent
    max-width="300"
    @input="$emit('input', $event)"
  >
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title
        class="text-h5"
        style="word-break: break-word"
      >
        Title Dialog
      </v-card-title>
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-spacer />
        <v-btn
          color="green darken-1"
          text
          @click="close"
        >
          Cancel
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn
          class="primary"
          @click="onBtnSubmit"
        >
          Confirm
        </v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>


export default {
  name: 'Dialog',
  props: {
    dialog: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true
    },
    buttonActionName: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    method: {
      type: Function,
      required: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    close() {
      this.$emit('close-dialog')
    },
    onReportBtnSubmit() {
      if (this.buttonActionName.length > 0) {
        this.method(this.buttonActionName)
      } else {
        this.method()
      }
      this.close()
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

I assumed that you understand the concept of passing the functions through `props` attribute in Vue.

```
// This dialog will pass function `firstBtnSubmit` without param name
<Dialog
   :dialog.sync="firstBtnDialog"
   :method="firstBtnSubmit"
   button-action-name=""
   @close-dialog="firstBtnDialog= false;"
 />
<v-btn
  @click="showDialogFirstBtn">
  firstBtnClick
</v-btn>

// This dialog will pass function `secondBtnSubmit` with param name
<Dialog
   :dialog.sync="secondBtnDialog"
   :method="secondBtnSubmit"
   button-action-name="id1"
   @close-dialog="secondBtnDialog = false;"
 />
<v-btn
  @click="showDialogSecBtn">
  secondBtnClick
</v-btn>

// you can create a third button below by yourself.

export default {
 data() {
   return {
     firstBtnDialog: false,
     secondBtnDialog: false,
     thirdBtnDialog: false,
  },
 methods: {
    firstBtnSubmit() {
       // Do your stuff
    },
    secondBtnSubmit(param) {
       // do your staff with param 
    },
    thirdBtnSubmit () {
       // do your stuff
    },
    // To trigger dialog to pop up 
    showDialogFirstBtn() {
       this.firstBtnDialog = true;
    },
    showDialogSecBtn() {
       this.secondBtnDialog= true;
    },
    showDialogThirdBtn() {
       this.thirdBtnDialog= true;
    }
  }
}
```

**Note**

I do NOT own all contents that I wrote here.

All contents I got from different site

[Concept to pass function as props](https://michaelnthiessen.com/pass-function-as-prop/)

[How to use reusable component in Vue: Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66206983/how-to-implement-a-reusable-vuetify-dialog)